# Cleaner way to do pytest fixture parameterization based on command-line switch?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, pytest, fixtures, parameterization

I've technically already solved the problem I was working on, but I can't help but feel like my solution is ugly:

I've got a pytest suite that I can run in two modes: Local Mode (for developing tests; everything just runs on my dev box through Chrome), and Seriousface Regression Testing Mode (for CI; the suite gets run on a zillion browsers and OSes). I've got a command-line flag to toggle between the two modes, `--test-local`. If it's there, I run in local mode. If it's not there, I run in seriousface mode. Here's how I do it:

```
# contents of conftest.py
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--test-local", action="store_true", default=False, help="run locally instead of in seriousface mode")

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if "dummy" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        if metafunc.config.getoption("--test-local"):
            driverParams = [(True, None)]
        else:
            driverParams = [(False, "seriousface setting 1"), (False, "seriousface setting 2")]
        metafunc.parameterize("dummy", driverParams)

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def driver(dummy):
    _driver = makeDriverStuff(dummy[0], dummy[1])
    yield _driver
    _driver.cleanup()

@pytest.fixture
def dummy():
    pass
```

The problem is, that `dummy` fixture is hideous. I've tried having `pytest_generate_tests` parameterize the `driver` fixture directly, but it ends up *replacing* the fixture rather than just feeding stuff into it, so `cleanup()` never gets called when the test finishes. Using the dummy lets me replace the dummy with my parameter tuple, so that that gets passed into `driver()`.

But, to reiterate, what I have *does work*, it just feels like a janky hack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try a different approach: instead of dynamically selecting the parameter set for the test, declare ALL parameter sets on it, but deselect the irrelevant ones at launch time.

```
# r.py
import pytest

real = pytest.mark.real
mock = pytest.mark.mock

@pytest.mark.parametrize('a, b', [
    real((True, 'serious 1')),
    real((True, 'serious 2')),
    mock((False, 'fancy mock')),
    (None, 'always unmarked!'),
])
def test_me(a, b):
    print([a, b])
```

Then run it as follows:

```
pytest -ra -v -s   r.py -m real        # strictly marked sets
pytest -ra -v -s   r.py -m mock        # strictly marked sets
pytest -ra -v -s   r.py -m 'not real'  # incl. non-marked sets
pytest -ra -v -s   r.py -m 'not mock'  # incl. non-marked sets
```

Also, `skipif` marks can be used for the selected parameter set (different from deselecting). They are natively supported by pytest. But the syntax is quite ugly. See more in the pytest's [Skip/xfail with parametrize](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/skipping.html#skip-xfail-with-parametrize) section.

The official manual also contains exactly the same case as in your question in [Custom marker and command line option to control test runs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html#custom-marker-and-command-line-option-to-control-test-runs). However, it is also not as elegant as `-m` test deselection, and is more suitable for complex run-time conditions, not on the apriori known structure of the tests.

Comment: That's definitely nicer than dummy fixtures! Are there ways to set this up with more than just 2 configuration-marks (i.e. so I could have an arbitrary number of modes, e.g. benchtesting, standard CI suite, super-mega-hardcore-prerelease-suite)?